# Trying to use coffeescript in a rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm trying to use some coffee script in an engine but as soon as i name a file with:

```
*.js.coffee or *.coffee
```

an error is triggered and i can't load the page:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError at /mylocation
SyntaxError: unexpected IDENTIFIER
```

The page won't load. My coffeescript is working in another app (Actually i'm trying to extract the logic from the main app to an engine). When i try using it in the engine it failed if it's a .coffee file.

I have in gemfile of the core app:

```
gem 'coffee-rails'
```

In the engine gemspec:

```
s.add_dependency 'coffee-rails'
```

If i rename the file to *.js the page loads but of course i see the syntax error in the js console.

Any idea where i should look or what should i do to use coffeescript in my engine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my stupid error, the file i was playing with was and old js file and when i converted it to coffee i forgot to change the comments lines ( // to # )...

Answer (score 0):

"Unexpected identifier" means that you have a variable you're trying to reference that hasn't been declared. Possibly a function which is not within the coffescript callback?

Make sure you pass all the variables you're trying to use.

Comment: Hi JellyFishBoy, the problem is that the loading of the page doesn't work. It's not the javascript that is not execute. For exemple if i comment every thing in the file it's also not working. But if i rename the file the page loads and of course the js error occurs because it's not converted in js. I can edit my post to copy the script but it's a really basic one that trigger a select2 dropdown list. Nothing special there i can write it in js to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the Gemfile.lock and doing a fresh bundle install to ensure to coffee gem is installing correctly?

Comment: In the main app or in the engine?

Comment: I'll try in few sec but in the core app where the engine is used the coffeescript files are working fine.